# how to wrap text in boundfield column in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am having a boundfield column and in that column if i entered a string(without spaces) of length 15, there is no problem. But if the string is more than 15, the text is not wrapped. I gave the command column.ItemStyle.Wrap=true; But its not working. I have fixed the width of the column.

How to wrap the text in the boundfield if a string more 15 characters. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, for my previous solution.

You could use `<br/>` to break for each 15 characters.

Example if you string result is `1234567890123456`. It gone be `123456789012345<br/>6`

Here some snippets code:

```
string myString = "mondayfridaysaturday";
string result = string.Empty;
for (int i=0; i<myString.Length; i++)
    result += (i%14==0&&i!=0) ? (myString[i].ToString()+"<br/>") : myString[i].ToString();
```

Comment: -1 for perpetuating the problem with your solution.  The OP is having trouble making his text wrap -- your solution ensures that his text will NOT wrap.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, drove me insane. Turns out I had `RowStyle-Wrap` set `false`, which in turn was overriding the `itemstyle-wrap` in the boundfield column. Change your .aspx to `<RowStyle Wrap="True" />`

Answer (score 3):

Supported in all but Opera (Even works in IE6!):

```
.wraptext { word-wrap: break-word;}
```

[More info here](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Breaking-Up-Long-Lines-With-No-Spaces-In-Them)

Edit --
Woops, just found another resource that handles Opera, too!

[Extra resource](http://www.webstylepress.com/wrapping-text/)

Comment: Please post your code.  We need to know what kind of control you're using, and whether or not you're using template fields.